# Input/output codes execution (what's executed first, the client or the server?)

Tags: java, io

We just started studying IO codes and there is a certain point I don't understand this problem :
Here's the server Code :

```
public final class SuccServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (ServerSocket s0 = new ServerSocket(5108);
     Socket s = s0.accept();
     BufferedReader r =
       new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream(),
                   US_ASCII));
     BufferedWriter w =
       new BufferedWriter(
         new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(),
                    US_ASCII))) {
      int i = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
      int i1 = i + 1;
      w.write(String.valueOf(i1));
      w.write('\n');
      w.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the Client code :

```
public final class SuccClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 5108);
     BufferedReader r =
       new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream(),
                   US_ASCII));
     BufferedWriter w =
       new BufferedWriter(
         new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(),
                    US_ASCII))) {
      int i = 2019;
      w.write(String.valueOf(i));
      w.write('\n');
      w.flush();
      int succ = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
      System.out.printf("succ(%d) = %d%n", i, succ);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

First the connection is established so the accept() creats the socket, then I don't understand how the code will work(chronologically), why is the client's write instruction

```
      w.write(String.valueOf(i));
```

that is executed first and not the server's

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
```

, and why after writing 2019 does the client wait for the server's response ? he could simply continue the code by executing

```
      int succ = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
```

without waiting for the server to respond him with 2020 ?

These  questions could seem simple but they don't let me understand more difficult code.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put it's because `readLine()` and `accept()` are [***blocking***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing)).

"In computing, a process is an instance of a computer program that is being executed. A process always exists in exactly one process state. A ***process that is blocked is one that is waiting for some event, such as a resource becoming available or the completion of an I/O operation***"

Program would hang at `readline()` until newline or end of stream is reached, just like when `accept()` is called on the server it hangs until a client connects.

edit: [***Here is another explanation with focus on network sockets***](https://medium.com/coderscorner/tale-of-client-server-and-socket-a6ef54a74763).

Comment: I ran some tests, I don't really remember how I got there, but at some point readLine would give me an empty line and i had to call it a second time in a row so that it gives me what i needed, how is that possible if readLine is blocking ?

Comment: @lno If it gave an empty line you sent an empty line. Blocking has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @Ino That's a really good question, but if I don't know exactly what you did, I can't say for sure. But I am sure that `readline()` is blocking. You can always try it out yourself, like call `readline()` and right after that `System.out.println("readLine() really is blocking");` Also in my anwser i added link to a much better explanation focused on sockets